# How to make Elasticsearch sort/prefer hits with exactly matching strings first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch

I'm using default analyzers and indexing. So let's say I have this simple mapping:

```
"question": {
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "answer": {
            "properties": {
                "text": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(that was an example. sorry if it has typos)

Now, I perform the following search.

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "yes correct",
            "fields": ["answer.text"]
        }
    }
}
```

The results will score a `text` value like "yes correct." (doc id value `1`) higher than simply "yes correct" (without a period, doc id value `181`). Both hits have the same score value, but the hits array lists the one with the smaller doc id first. I understand that the default index option includes sorting by doc id, so how do I exclude that one attribute and still use the rest of the default options?

I'm not setting any custom analyzers, so everything is using default values for Elasticsearch 2.0.

Comment: Note that `"fields`"  should be `"default_field"` otherwise the query won't work. Both get the exact same score on my end. Can you show the sample documents you're basing yourself on?

Comment: Sorry, I think I had a typo in my code. Using `fields` works for me and changing it to `default_field` doesn't change the hits scores. I also didn't realize the scores were exactly the same. *oops*

Comment: My bad, sorry, `"fields"` works of course, need some coffee :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a use case for [Dis Max Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html)

> A query that generates the union of documents produced by its
>   subqueries, and that scores each document with the maximum score for
>   that document as produced by any subquery, plus a tie breaking
>   increment for any additional matching subqueries.

So following that, you need to make your answer score as an exact match and give it highest boost. You'll have to use a custom analyzer for that. That'd be your mappings:

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_keyword": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "question": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "answer": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "text": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_keyword",
              "fields": {
                "stemmed": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "standard"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your test data:

```
PUT /test/question/1
{
  "title": "title nr1",
  "answer": [
    {
      "text": "yes correct."
    }
  ]
}

PUT /test/question/2
{
  "title": "title nr2",
  "answer": [
    {
      "text": "yes correct"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when you're querying for `"yes correct."` using such query:

```
POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "tie_breaker": 0.7,
      "boost": 1.2,
      "queries": [
        {
          "match": {
            "answer.text": {
              "query": "yes correct.",
              "type": "phrase"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "answer.text.stemmed": {
              "query": "yes correct.",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You get this output:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.37919715,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "question",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.37919715,
            "_source": {
               "title": "title nr1",
               "answer": [
                  {
                     "text": "yes correct."
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "question",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.11261705,
            "_source": {
               "title": "title nr2",
               "answer": [
                  {
                     "text": "yes correct"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

If you run very same query without trailing dot, which then becomes `"yes correct"`, you're getting this result:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.37919715,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "question",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.37919715,
            "_source": {
               "title": "title nr2",
               "answer": [
                  {
                     "text": "yes correct"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "question",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.11261705,
            "_source": {
               "title": "title nr1",
               "answer": [
                  {
                     "text": "yes correct."
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

By the way, I'd recommend to always use [Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-match-query.html) query when performing text search. Taken from documentation:

> **Comparison to query_string / field**
>
> ---
>
> The match family of queries
>   does not go through a "query parsing" process. It does not support
>   field name prefixes, wildcard characters, or other "advanced"
>   features. For this reason, chances of it failing are very small / non
>   existent, and it provides an excellent behavior when it comes to just
>   analyze and run that text as a query behavior (which is usually what a
>   text search box does). Also, the phrase_prefix type can provide a
>   great "as you type" behavior to automatically load search results.

Comment: Thanks for recommending `match`. I've just started working with Elasticsearch and there's a lot to take in. I thought it would be as easy as setting up an index and start querying! haha

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what I would have to use as `"Other stuff"`. I just want to match `"yes correct"` -- with exact matches sorted and/or scored higher than something like `"yes correct."`.

Comment: I misunderstood you a bit. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: @user5243421 I've updated my answer with mappings, sample data and query. It works as you expect.

Comment: Wow, this is very cool!! I figured I needed a custom analyzer, but I didn't think to also add a query-time boost. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I wish I could upvote you more.

Comment: I'm just wondering, what if I wanted the keyword to match substrings, too? Like I'd like `"correct"` to match `"yes correctness"`. The current setup wouldn't allow that; seems to be returning 0 hits...

Comment: Hi. You'd have to setup a separate analyzer that would transform both correct and correctness into same token, so both would become correct as a token. Then you would need to run match query against that. Please read about stemming, normalization and token filters in elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on what to study up on. From my understanding, it looks like I might something that matches the as-you-type functionality on other sites.

Comment: Your probably speaking about auto complete? These can be done using nGrams or completion suggesters. Of course, you might want to wrap it up in dis max as well.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch or rather Lucene scoring does not take into account the relative positioning of the tokens. It utlizes 3 different criterias to do the same

1. Term frequency - Frequency at which the search terms is present in
   the document
2. Inverse document frequency - Number of occurrence of the search term
   in the entire database. The more the occurance , the more the common
   is the search term and less the importance it has in search
3. Field length normalization - Number of tokens present in the target
   field.

You can learn more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html).

Comment: This is confusing because it says that `string` fields are by default analyzed wrt to positions: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/index-options.html

Comment: The position is also stored , but then its not used for computing relevancy.

Comment: So can we tell Elasticsearch to use position in calculating relevancy? I feel like my case should be common enough that I should be able to find the answer somewhere, but I'm having a lot of troubling searching for the right terms...

Comment: I was standing in your same shoe some month ago. And surprisingly there is no module which supports this. I presumed the reason being performance toll on doing all the calculation. If there is only one occurrence of this term its fine , but then how to do it if there are multiple occurrence of the search terms in relatively consecutive manner. We can implement this using script though